# Write arbitrary map and reduce function

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to write my own map and reduce function in mapreduce framework
How can I do that??(my programming language is java)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extend from the Mapper and Reducer class and override the methods you need.

Comment: Which two implementations? Implementing an Interface and extending a Class?

Comment: I know that but in mapred examples it use two type of implementation. in WordCount example the map class(TokenizerMapper) extends Mapper but in TeraGen example the map class(SortGenMapper) extends MapReduceBase and implements Mapper. what is difference between these two approach??

Comment: MapReduceBase is deprecated, you should not use that anymore.

Comment: Yes, Implementing an Interface and extending a class.

Comment: Implementing an Interface is deprecated too. Just go with the Mapper and Reducer class.

Answer (score 2):

Start by reading the [MapReduce Tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html), then start implementing of your application.  If you run into problems, feel free to ask a more specific question.